# Reposition 'absolute' elements on web page - CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, position

I really like the Image Slider on this site home page: http://festival.co.nz/

However, I was wondering, **is it possible to move the 'previous' and 'next' buttons to be on either side of the main 'active' image**. Currently they are fixed to the extreme left & right.

The styling of these elements is handled by this **CSS file**: http://css.festival.co.nz/yk-minifier/72cdcb814eb3e3beaa50436a9f869b1c.css however I'm really unsure where to begin if I was to try and move the buttons to be on either side of the centre image.

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more I think about this, it probably makes more sense to use media queries for the key desktop computer sizes and adjust accordingly.

Sorry for the time waster here guys :(

Answer (score 2):

Change the following on line 397 of the css file:

from

```
a.prev_event {
    left: 0;
}
```

to

```
a.prev_event {
left: 50%;
    margin-left: -470px;
}
```

And on line 401, change

```
a.next_event {
    right: 0;
}
```

to

```
a.next_event {
    margin-right: -470px;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Coool. Will take a quick look-see at this end. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: You can check this real easy by using developer tools for the browser your using. In Chrome for example, press F12, search for "next_event" and "prev_event". When selecting the HTML part you can edit the CSS in the right side-bar. This way you can see the changes live, and you can play around with it until you are satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Set `left:240px` instead of `left:0` for `a.prev_event` in your css.

Also set `right:240px` instead of `right:0` for `a.next_event` in your css.

Hope this will give you result that you want.

Comment: I think I'll use media queries and a combination of this to set the buttons to different positions based on screen size. Thanks for your advice here, very much appreciated.